# Use of Extended Features is no longer available after saving text in pdf acroform pdfboxafter saving text in pdf acroform pdfbox

Tags: pdfbox

After adding text to pdf acroform using pdfbox programatically, i am getting **Use of Extended Features is no longer available** while opening the file in adobe acrobat reader.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2858

Comment: Extended features in Adobe Reader are activated by the presence of a *valid* usage rights signature in the pdf displayed. Your form field manipulation seems to have invalidated the signature, though. Thus, change your code to not invalidate that signature.

Comment: HI @mkl can you provide me some sample code where i can tell not to invalidate the signature while filling the form. Thank you